# Can a kitsune's tail be prehensile?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

I know other tailed races like kobolds and tieflings have [feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/grasping-tail-tiefling/) and abilities that let them use their tails for things like retrieving items from a pouch.

Is there a way for a kitsune to gain the ability to do something similar? Pretty much anything is fair game as long as it's the kitsune's own tail.

If there is, and they get the Magical Tail feat(s), could they hold multiple things with them, one in each tail?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### It's possible, but feat intensive

The [Blood of the Beast](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9oo8) player companion presents us with the [Human Guise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/human-guise/) feat, which kitsune qualify for due to their [Change Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-kitsune) ability.

> You count as both human and your race for the purpose of taking character options, such as archetypes, feats, spells, traits, and prestige classes.

This will allow your character to qualify for [Racial Heritage (Human)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/racial-heritage/).

> Choose another humanoid race. You count as both human and that race for any effects related to race.

Which, finally, allows you to pick [Grasping Tail (Tiefling)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/grasping-tail-tiefling/), or [similar feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/tail-terror-combat-kobold).

Its worth noting that Racial Heritage will allow you to count as *any* one humanoid race you want.

About [Magical Tail](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/magical-tail-kitsune/), you certainly could grab more than one item, as the feat does not mention *which* tail has to do it. But do note that your character is only allowed [one swift action per turn](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Swift-Actions).

### This changed with Planar Adventures

If your group is playing with [Planar Adventures](https://paizo.com/products/btpya1am), the feat got reprinted (as pointed out in @Brandenfascher's answer) and its new requirement is simply that your character must have a tail, which kitsunes do. Everything else is unchanged.

> [Grasping Tail](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/grasping-tail/)
>
> Prerequisite(s): You must have a tail.

But note that the book didn't mention that this feat changes how [Grasping Tail (Tiefling)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/grasping-tail-tiefling/) works or that it replaces it. Which means that this is a different feat and tiefling characters may still use their racial feat instead.

Comment: Just a note, Racial heritage (Human) requires the type be humanoid so Tiefling wouldn't be a valid choice.

Comment: Unless your heritage possessed the **Pass for Human** racial trait.

Comment: huh, I missed that they added that alternate racial trait. I could definitely see some GMs denying the use of tiefling on the grounds that it is an alternate trait.  Interestingly the pass for human trait implies that a tiefling doesn't have a tail, but the grasping tail feat doesn't have an explicit requirement for one.

Answer (score 9):

Paizo's [Planar Adventures](https://paizo.com/products/btpya1am) rulebook released a new version of [Grasping Tail](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Grasping%20Tail) that has primarily changed the prerequisites of the feat:

> Prerequisite(s): You must have a tail.

The original [Grasping Tail](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/grasping-tail-tiefling) from Advanced Race Guide had prerequisites requiring the tiefling race.

With the new Planar Adventures feat, Racial Heritage is no longer required for the kitsune, as it appears that any race that bears a tail can benefit from this feat. Also note that Planar Adventures included additional feats for Grasping Tail, namely [Mischievous Tail](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Mischievous%20Tail) and [Lashing Tail](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Lashing%20Tail).

I would assume that these feats would work for all tails of a multi-tailed kitsune.

However, as an important side-note, Lashing Tail appears to have wording such to prevent one from making more than one natural attack when making a tail slap attack with that feat:

> Due to the inherent awkwardness of attacking with your tail, you can’t make a tail slap attack and other natural weapon attacks as part of the same full attack. Treat your tail slap attack as a secondary attack if you also attack with a manufactured weapon as part of a full-attack action.

I would assume this is to prevent a multi-tailed race from gaining use of multiple natural attacks with all of their tails, so unfortunately, no nine-tails worth of slaps.

Answer (score 4):

Rogue Genius Games publishes [*Racial Prestige: Kyubi Paragon*](https://www.opengamingstore.com/collections/rogue-genius-games/products/racial-prestige-kyubi-paragon) that includes the prestige class **kyubi paragon** (not yet available on the *d20PFSRD*) that does pretty much exactly what you're looking for and more. I recommend checking it out if you're interested in playing a kitsune like one from a myth or folktale.

Comment: I'd also like to mention it's not currently on PFSRD, and has recently been released. so you may need to purchase the doc. I have done so myself and it's been worth it so far. the prestige class is really flavorful and surprisingly balanced. only a few grammatical errors and maybe one questionable ability. there's a lot of scaling in the class! I hope you check it out.

Comment: I would detail the ability but I think i'd rather wait until it's on PFSRD to avoid any issues I might have with intellectual property

Comment: Encountering IP issues with a *summary* is rare. So long as the summary's vague, everything's cool (e.g. *At level 1 you get a tail that can grab stuff*). However, this answer really should mention in what book the prestige class is/will be printed.

Comment: https://www.opengamingstore.com/collections/rogue-genius-games/products/racial-prestige-kyubi-paragon

Racial prestige Kyubi Paragon, It is "printed" as in it's a PDF. I think it's not available in print.

Answer (score 0):

A [monkey belt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-monkey/) can allow any character to temporarily have 
a prehensile tail. Because this tail can "manipulate objects about as well as the wearer’s normal limbs," it should be able to retrieve stored items. It is more expensive and less permanent than having a non-magical prehensile tail attached at all times. You can probably talk your GM into house-ruling that this belt turns the Kitsune's tail prehensile instead of creating a prehensile tail.

Having a monkey belt tail would not interact with the magical tail feat.

Comment: The original question was whether or not **abilities** are available. While it is a very cool item, I am not entire certain that it answers the question :)

Comment: @BanjoFox It allows a kitsune to gain the ability to use a tail to retrieve items from a pouch.

Comment: It may give the Kitsune the ability, but the question isn't asking that. OP is asking if the existing Kitsune tail can do this (and, if so, how?)

Comment: @NautArch "Is there a way for a kitsune to gain the ability to do something similar?" It doesn't say that it has to be the kitsune's tail.

Comment: It isn't a way for specifically a kitsune to do so though. It's a way for anyone with a belt slot to do so, including humans, kitsune, kobolds, and sharks. The question is asking for a way for a kitsune to use their already-existing tail as a prehensile tail, as a kobold or a tiefling can.

Comment: I figured that using the kitsune's own tail was implied in the question. Do I need to make it explicit?

Comment: @Pyritie - Unfortunately there is often a need to be clear and very explicit when asking such questions. This leads to better answers and less discussion :)

Comment: @Pyritie The question you originally wrote is somewhat broader than the question you edited to. That can be a deliberate strategy to allow room for slightly more creative answers.

Comment: I don't think there are any ways to do this by RAW so any answer longer than "no" is necessarily going to involve either ideas that are close enough to be in the same ballpark or just begging your GM for permission to refluff or houserule the pre-reqs for a different thing.